# Using curb gem and libcurl on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, libcurl, curb

I am trying to install the curb gem, which is libcurl bindings for Ruby, and of course I need to have "A working (lib)curl installation, with development stuff" installed on my computer. So, I went to the cURL Download Wizard and downloaded [this package](http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip).

But adding the bin into my PATH does not produce improvement and I still get an error when I try to install the curb gem, such as:

> extconf.rb:19: Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h
>   (RuntimeError)

Even though, curl is already in the PATH.

EDIT: I also tried raking the gem, as per [the instructions](http://github.com/taf2/curb). It fails saying "make failed" and throwing a bunch of errors like this:

> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/curb-0.7.7.1/ext/curb_postfield.c:76:
>   undefined reference to
>   `_imp__curl_formadd'

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a very old question, but I had this exact problem today and found the instructions on someone else's site. These worked for me so I thought I would share them since people with this issue are most likely to come across StackOverflow first: http://jes.al/2012/10/installing-curb-gem-on-windows-7/

In a nutshell:

1. Get the 32-bit development version of curl (see my notes below)
2. Add the curl bin directory to your PATH
3. Run the following command (replacing the paths to curl as necessary)

   `gem install curb --platform=ruby -- -- --with-curl-lib="C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/bin" --with-curl-include="C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/include"`

A couple of personal notes:

- Even though I am on 64-bit Windows 7, I had to download the 32-bit **libcurl** version under "Win32 - Generic", identified as "Win32 2000/XP zip".
- I got the error `c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:246:in 'initialize': Permission denied - mkmftmp1.log (Errno::EACCES)` while installing the gem. This rather [messed up page here](http://thr3ads.net/rubyinstaller-devel/2008/04/316817-Installer3-rake-compile-problem) suggested that it might be a problem with my anti-virus, and that just retrying a couple of times might work, and indeed, it did.

Answer (score 0):

Execute Below command for windows only and its works

gem install curb --platform=mswin32